# Hibernate Docs Contradiction: SQL Normalization vs Entity Mapping on Multiple Tables

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, normalization

The Hibernate documentation states the following:

> 5.1.6.5. Mapping one entity to several tables
>
> While not recommended for a fresh schema, some legacy databases force
>   your[sic] to map a single entity on several tables.

I have done a lot of reading on database normalization, and I don't really understand how you can both normalize a database and NOT map an entity on several database tables, unless you map several different entities and do a weird join statement manually.  Or, you map 7 different entities and transfer them to one POJO.  Is there somewhere that shows how to develop a "fresh schema" that is both normalized and takes a single entity to turn from database data to a java object?

Also, I understand that complete normalization isn't necessary in today's world of cheap storage, but I just found this statement to be at odds with everything else I've read.  I am looking for a balance of normalized to de-normalized, but haven't found a simple way with the the Java Persistence API.

**EDIT:**

Example:

If I have a user Entity with the following:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    long id;        
    String name;
    String email;

    int countryCode;

    List<Images> uploadedImages;
}
```

I am not going to store the user's country name and collection of images on the same table, rather I will have the country on one table:

```
Table Countries    Country_Code    Country_Name
                   AF              Afghanistan etc....
```

with country code and country name, then on , and uploaded images on a separate table with user id's,

```
Table UploadedImages    User_Id      Image_Name    Image_Url
                        1            Hello.jpg     Amazon S3
                        1            Goodbye.jpg   Photobucket
```

So how do I do this with only one entity?  Or do I get three separate entities from the database using information from the first entity? As you can tell, I'm a bit confused on the basic schema, How would I translate the data above to a java object?

Comment: Could you provide an example of an entity that, inyour opinion, should be mapped to several tables?

Comment: If i'e got a User entity with a unique id and an email address how am I meant to map that to several tables?

Comment: @BedwyrHumphreys - I wish that was the only information I needed to store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your example

```
@Entity
public class User {
    long id;        
    String name;
    String email;

    int countryCode;

    List<Images> uploadedImages;
}
```

Here you have 3 entities - a User, a Country and an Image entity with each one probably mapping to 3 tables - one entity per table and a join table for the list of images.

So your User class then becomes

```
@Entity
public class User {

    long id;        

    String name;

    String email;

    Country country

    List<Images> uploadedImages;
}

@Entity
public class Country {

    long id;        

    String name;

}

@Entity
public class Image{

    long id;        

    String name;

    String url;

}
```

And you'd add annotations to map the properties to the correct tables and columns.

Comment: Thank you.  This answer helped me get over a large conceptual hump.  I wasn't differentiating between parent entities and child entities as separate, and not being able to distinguish the two made designing my db and objects very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

What the documentation says has nothing to do with data normalization. This has to do with data partition/table optimization. So, if you have a table with a column that holds a big binary, you probably don't want that to be part of the same table as the main data. This was more common in the past, as data considered small by today's measures were considered "big" back then.

Normalization, on the other hand, is very welcome in OOP (and Hibernate). It's all about keeping things on their places, to [minimize redundancy and dependency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)